# Получение снимка с IP-камеры по протоколу ONVIF

Tags: python, python-2.x, ip, камера, onvif

Мне необходимо получить снимок с IP-камеры (библиотека ONVIF для 2.7). Код и ошибка такая:

```
cam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.22.19', 80, '***', '***')
media = cam.create_media_service()
media.GetSnapshotUri()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 31, 
in wrapped raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Profile token does not exist
```

Пробовал получить токен через `GetVideoEncoderConfigurations`, и выскакивает ошибка:

```
token = media.GetVideoEncoderConfigurations()
media.GetSnapshotUri(token[0]._token)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 31, 
in wrapped raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: Method instance argument 
after ** must be a mapping, not Text
```

Как получить этот токен или другой способ получение снимка?

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

Обращение через `media.Func()` следует задать параметр типа `__dict__` с именованным ключем: `{"ProfileToken" : token}`

**UPD**

Надо читать документацию(((